# Need to use forEach to return the number of elements for which the 'callback' function result is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback, boolean

I need to use forEach to solve this solution and I'm a bit stuck! I don't think I can use 'count' for this like I can with a for loop because I can't return inside the forEach. So what I've written is still really wrong, but this is what I have so far:

```
function count(arr, callback) {
  let result = 0;
  arr.forEach(ele => {
    if (ele === callback())  {
       result += ele.length;
}
  });
  return result;
}
```

But it's not passing all of the tests:

```
>
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3);
Expected: 1 but got: 0
>
count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1);
Expected: 3 but got: 0
>
count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2);
Expected: 2 but got: 0
>
count(['a', 'b'], (e) => e === 'd');
Expected: 0 OK!
>
count([], (e) => e === 'd');
Expected: 0 OK!
```

Could anyone please offer any help? Just to reiterate I do need to use forEach to solve this!

Comment: Inline: `[1, 2, 3, 4].filter(v => v > 1).length; // 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `callback` is a function that takes an element and checks if it matches a value

`(e) => e === 2` => Takes  an `e` and checks if e is 2

So you need to pass the array item when iterating with forEach

Also for each match you increment `result` by 1 and not `ele.length`

```js
function count(arr, callback) {
  let result = 0;
  arr.forEach(ele => {
    if (callback(ele))  { // Pass ele to the callback
       result += 1; // Add 1 to result for every match
}
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(`Expected: ${count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your solution,

1. You are calling the `callback` but not passing the value
2. From the `callback` you are expecting a boolean value, so again `ele === callback()` is not needed.

The reason why it's not working because `ele === callback()` is never getting satisfied.

So, you can modify the code like

```js
function count(arr, callback) {
  let result = 0;
  arr.forEach(ele => {
    //call the callback with the element
    if (callback(ele)) {
    //Update the count by 1 when truthy value returned from callback
      result += 1;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3));
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3));
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1));
console.log(count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2));
console.log(count(['a', 'b'], (e) => e === 'd'));
console.log(count([], (e) => e === 'd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in if block. You need to pass the element to `callback()` and then check if its returning true or false. If true, increment result by 1.

```js
    function count(arr, callback) {
      let result = 0;
      arr.forEach(ele => {
        if ( callback(ele))  {
           result += 1;
    }
      });
      return result;
    }
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e === 3));
console.log(count([1, 2, 3, 4], (e) => e > 1));
console.log(count([2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8], (e) => e === 2));
console.log(count(['a', 'b'], (e) => e === 'd'));
console.log(count([], (e) => e === 'd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a filter solution:

```js
function count(arr, callback) {
  const result = arr.filter(callback);
  
  return result.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function count(arr, callback) {
    let result =[];
    arr.forEach(ele => {
      if (callback(ele))  {
         result.push(ele);
      }
    });
    return result.length;
}
```